# Switch from Mobile view to Desktop view by PHP session

Tags: php, session

I have done the switching from mobile view to desktop view, but how do I show the menu if desktop view is on? I want to show "Switch to Mobile View"

Here is my code

```
<?php session_start(); ?>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">

<?php
if($_GET['show_desktop_mode'] == 'true') {
    $_SESSION['desktopmode'] = 'true';
} else if($_GET['show_desktop_mode'] == 'false') {
    $_SESSION['desktopmode'] = 'false';
}

if($_SESSION['desktopmode'] == 'true') {
    /* DESKTOP MODE */
    ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=1170">
    <?php
} else {
    // DEFAULT
    ?>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <?php
}
?>
```

And here Goes in my footer

```
<?php if($_SESSION['desktopmode'] == 'false') { ?>
    <li id="desktop"><a href="http://example.com/?show_desktop_mode=true">Switch To Desktop Mode</a></li>
<?php } elseif($_SESSION['desktopmode'] == 'true') { ?>
    <li id="mobile"><a href="http://example.com/?show_desktop_mode=false">Switch to Mobile Mode</a></li>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: What is the value of `var_dump($_SESSION['desktopmode']);`? Have you got `session_start()`?

Comment: Yes i start the Session already in the header....see the code